# Providing multi-version databases for backward compatibility for production applications/databases

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, architecture

How can I manage multiple versions of a database easily?

I have some data (as views as selects for data originating in tables from other schemas), which other database may reference using various means including database synonyms & links.

I wish to provide a sort of interface/guarantee in-case future for applications/databases which use this data. All of this is for in the event i need to update the views for correctness or applicability inside my database.

How can i achieve this in a maintained, controlled and easy way?

I am using Oracle 10g if that matters.

Comment: You could say this is 'master data management'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the 11gR2 feature: [Edition-Based Redefinition](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_URL?remark=ranked&urlname=http:%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fdocs%2Fcd%2FE11882_01%2Fappdev.112%2Fe10471%2Fadfns_editions.htm%23ADFNS020). It allows you to have multiple versions of views and packages available in the database.

You can read more in a [Christian Antognini's paper](http://antognini.ch/papers/EditionBasedRedefinition20100112.pdf).

Comment: + 1 for the link to Christian's paper - Thanks Vincent

Comment: Impressive! I am using 10g, sigh! :b